# How to change canvas fillStyle with collision detection?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So i've made a Breakout game following [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Workflows/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript) which was fairly simple but one of the optional exercises is to get the ball to change its colour whenever it hits the side of the canvas. The site doesn't tell you how to do this, and i've not been able to find any answers after a couple hours' Googling.

I've just started leaning Javascript and this is practise for a simple game i'm making for college, the idea is the knowledge of how to change colour will be more or less transferable to changing a sprite upon colliding with a wall.

For simplicity's sake, here's the code for just getting the ball to move around and bounce off walls:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ballRadius = 10;
var x = canvas.width/2;
var y = canvas.height-30;
var dx = 2;
var dy = -2;


function drawBall() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawBall();
    
    if(x + dx > canvas.width-ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
        dx = -dx;
        
    }
    if(y + dy > canvas.height-ballRadius || y + dy < ballRadius) {
        dy = -dy;
        
    }
    
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
}

setInterval(draw, 10);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Gamedev Canvas Workshop</title>
 <style>
  * {padding: 0; margin: 0;}
  canvas { background: #eee; display: block; margin: 0 auto;}
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>

<script>
  
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

The exercise specifies getting the ball to change to a new, random colour every time it collides, but for my purposes I only need to know how to get it to change once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do it.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ballRadius = 10;
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height - 30;
var dx = 2;
var dy = -2;
var color = "#0095DD"


function drawBall() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBall();

  if (x + dx > canvas.width - ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
    dx = -dx;
    color = "#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16);
  }
  if (y + dy > canvas.height - ballRadius || y + dy < ballRadius) {
    dy = -dy;
    color = "#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16);
  }

  x += dx;
  y += dy;
}

setInterval(draw, 10);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Gamedev Canvas Workshop</title>
  <style>
    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    canvas {
      background: #eee;
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>

  <script>
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Near the bottom of the code in the if statements you will see that when evaluated it sets the value of dx to a negative value, this is where the ball changes direction on either the x or y axis and can be used to detect collision.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ballRadius = 10;
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height - 30;
var dx = 2;
var dy = -2;
var color = 'green';

function drawBall(contact) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  color = (contact === true ? (color === 'green' ? 'pink' : 'green') : color);
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function draw() {
  var contact = false;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


  if (x + dx > canvas.width - ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
    dx = -dx;
    contact = true;

  }
  if (y + dy > canvas.height - ballRadius || y + dy < ballRadius) {
    dy = -dy;
    contact = true;

  }
  drawBall(contact);

  x += dx;
  y += dy;
}

setInterval(draw, 10);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Gamedev Canvas Workshop</title>
  <style>
    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    canvas {
      background: #eee;
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>

  <script>
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```